# When subnetting an AWS VPC, what are the pros and cons of subnetting by availability zone VS subnet type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet

Between the two scenarios discussed in Subnet Sizing section of an AWS [VPC Quickstart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/vpc/architecture.html#figure-1), why would you use one over the other?

The first scenario divided the VPC into subnet types and then further segmented it per Availability Zone.

```
VPC 10.0.0.0/16

Private subnets A       10.0.0.0/17
----------------------  -------------
Availability Zone 1     10.0.0.0/19         
Availability Zone 2     10.0.32.0/19
Availability Zone 3     10.0.64.0/19
Availability Zone 4     10.0.96.0/19

Public subnets          10.0.128.0/18
----------------------  -------------
Availability Zone 1     10.0.128.0/20
Availability Zone 2     10.0.144.0/20
Availability Zone 3     10.0.160.0/20
Availability Zone 4     10.0.176.0/20

Private subnets B ACL   10.0.192.0/19
----------------------  -------------
Availability Zone 1     10.0.192.0/21
Availability Zone 2     10.0.200.0/21
Availability Zone 3     10.0.208.0/21
Availability Zone 4     10.0.216.0/21

Spare subnet capacity   10.0.224.0/19
----------------------  -------------
Availability Zone 1     10.0.224.0/21
Availability Zone 2     10.0.232.0/21
Availability Zone 3     10.0.240.0/21
Availability Zone 4     10.0.248.0/21
```

The second scenario separated the CIDR scopes by dividing the VPC into Availability Zones and then into subnet types.

```
VPC 10.0.0.0/16

Availability Zone 1     10.0.0.0/18
----------------------  -------------
Private subnet A        10.0.0.0/19         
Public subnet           10.0.32.0/20
Private subnet B        10.0.48.0/21
Spare subnet capacity   10.0.56.0/21

Availability Zone 2     10.0.64.0/18
----------------------  -------------
Private subnet A        10.0.64.0/19
Public subnet           10.0.96.0/20
Private subnet B        10.0.112.0/21
Spare subnet capacity   10.0.120.0/21

Availability Zone 3     10.0.128.0/18
----------------------  -------------
Private subnet A        10.0.128.0/19
Public subnet           10.0.160.0/20
Private subnet B        10.0.176.0/21
Spare subnet capacity   10.0.184.0/21

Availability Zone 4     10.0.192.0/18
----------------------  -------------
Private subnet A        10.0.192.0/19
Public subnet           10.0.224.0/20
Private subnet B        10.0.240.0/21
Spare subnet capacity   10.0.248.0/21
```

Comment: What differences? They are technically same, except CIDR ranges.

Comment: In the 2nd scenario much easier to know the location of the instance/service at first glance. you will know that 0-63 is in AZ1, 64-127 in AZ1, and so on. the 1st scenario is easy on Security Group rules, because if you allow 10.0.0.0/17 , you will know that this rule will allow all instance on different availability zone to talk to each other for a particular subnet (eg. DB server subnet)

Comment: @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan, thank you for pointing out the ease with Security Group for scenario 1.